# Inconsistent behavior for "Unfollow" and "Too Many Pending Edits" popup modals

Tags: discussion, bug, edits, popup, follow-posts

If you click the follow button when viewing a question, and then click the same button which now says "Following" to unfollow the question, a popup modal appears like so:

[image]

If you hover the mouse over this popup window, it maintains the cursor as the default mouse icon:

[image]

When hovering the mouse over the "x" button, it changes background and allows you to close the menu by clicking:

[image]

I've noticed that in a similar popup modal for the "Too Many Pending Edits" indication, this behavior is slightly different.

When you hover the mouse over the pending edits modal the icon changes to a pointing hand and allows you to close the menu by clicking despite not being over the "x" button:

[image]

The logic for the "x" button is still present:

[image]

Obviously not a big deal, however I think that the "Too many pending edits" popup modal should be defined using the same logic as the other popup modals across the website. At least for consistency purposes :)

Comment: Literally unplayable.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Agreed, let's demand refunds!

Comment: It's a bit strange as it is supposed to use the same Stacks component for both. Possibly indeed a bug.

Comment: I view them as two different types of alerts. The first one just informs you that the action you've taken was a success and _it's displayed at the top_. The second, however, alerts you about a _failure_ and they chose to place it right below the action button. That's the key difference. Because it obstructs the view, one might need to manually dismiss it and I don't like being forced to go all the way to the end to do so. If something must change, I say either make the first one behave like the second (not the other way around) or place the second at the top too (not ideal; might be missed).

Comment: My vote is to make the first one behave like the second actually, too.

Comment: Maybe a personal CSS overwriting some SO class styles ?